# showing pop-up window after clicking on table cell in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I want to display a pop-up window on click on table cell in SharePoint hosted app I tried something but that is not working normally but when am pasting as it is javascript into console of browser in google chrome then that code works.
My code is as bellow

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    retrieveListItems();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        alert('Data:' + $(this).html().trim());
        alert('Row:' + $(this).parent().find('td').html().trim());
        alert('Column:' + $('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());
    });
});

 function retrieveListItems() {

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL
        var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("RoomData");
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var items = myList.getItems(query);
        ctx.load(items);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            PopulateValues3(items);
        }

    function PopulateValues3(items) {
            var itemInfo = '';
            var innerHtml = "<table border=1 class='display nowrap dataTable dtr-inline' id='example'><thead><tr><th> Name </th><th>email</th><th>Address</th><th>mobile</th></tr></thead> ";      
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
                if (currentListItem.get_item('Title') != null) {
                    innerHtml += "<tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>";
                }
            }
            $("#Data").html(innerHtml);
        }
```

so what going wrong with the app?am able to understand,because I have created a HTML of this and there it is working properly.

Comment: i resolved this issue,actually the '#example tbody' wasn't getting registerd for created HTML due to calling that separatly

Answer (score 1):

resolve by applying following change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        retrieveListItems();    
    });


    function retrieveListItems() {

            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL
            var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("RoomData");
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            var items = myList.getItems(query);
            ctx.load(items);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
            function onQuerySucceeded() {
                PopulateValues3(items);
            }

        function PopulateValues3(items) {
                var itemInfo = '';
                var innerHtml = "<table border=1 class='display nowrap dataTable dtr-inline' id='example'><thead><tr><th> Name </th><th>email</th><th>Address</th><th>mobile</th></tr></thead> ";      
                var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
                    if (currentListItem.get_item('Title') != null) {
                        innerHtml += "<tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>";
                    }
                }
                $("#Data").html(innerHtml);

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
            alert('Data:' + $(this).html().trim());
            alert('Row:' + $(this).parent().find('td').html().trim());
            alert('Column:' + $('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());
        });
            }
```